# Is it possible to send a pygame key event through bluetooth?

Tags: python-3.x, events, bluetooth, event-handling, pygame

I dont have any trial code to show as I dont know where to start even after researching this, but what I'm asking is if it's possible to send a pygame event.type like `pygame.KEYDOWN` from let's say a raspberry pi Zero to a pc using a bluetooth connection. So that the pc where the game is being run receives a event in `pygame.event.get()` to handle whatever code you have connected to that event.
Is this at all possible? If so, how would one send such an event? Establishing a bluetooth connection isnt the big issue, as there is documentation about that to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use [`pygame.event.post`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post) to put an event into the event queue.

`pygame.event.get` will receive it as usual. You maybe want to create a second thread to listen for your bluetooth events, and then just post a new pygame event in response.

Comment: Oh yeah, if I just run python with pygame on the sending part, the receiving end should have no issue handling it. I dont really think another thread will be needed in my case, but for something else it might be better yeah. Thanks!